# Can't Update Record Using Route53 API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I've setup a proper request to Amazon Route53 to create a new resource record.  This works flawlessly.

However, now I want to simply change the value of that record.  When I make the same request again with the new value, I get an exception with the following message.

> Tried to create resource record set [name='my.test.domain.', type='A']
>   but it already exists

In both requests, I've set the `Action` parameter to `CREATE` as the only alternative is `DELETE`.

I am using the PHP SDK's [`changeResourceRecordSets`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Route53.Route53Client.html#_changeResourceRecordSets) method, which starts it's description like...

> Use this action to create or change your authoritative DNS
>   information.

Elsewhere in the Amazon Web Services documentation, I also found the following snippet...

> If a resource record set does exist, Amazon Route 53 updates it with
>   the values in the request. Amazon Route 53 can update an existing
>   resource record set only when all of the following values match: Name,
>   Type, and SetIdentifier (for latency, weighted, and failover resource
>   record sets).

Does this mean I **need** the `SetIdentifier` parameter?  I don't have that since these are latency, weighted, or failover records.  Or are those the only records that can be updated like this?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to use the `UPSERT` action.  This action is not documented for the PHP SDK, but does exist.

**UPSERT** will update the record if it exists, or create it if it doesn't.